# Trying to match patterns and repeating numbers in a field

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, toad

I have a field [SSN] that stores social sec numbers. A lot of the records have a dummy value there and I am trying to find these in a Where statement. I am trying to find:

- rows that have repeating numbers within a range 0-9.
- rows that have numbers in this range that repeat 5 times

Examples of what I am trying to find:

```
00000
11111
22222
333333
444444
555555
666666
777777
```

I am using TOAD for Oracle at the moment to run the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find these patterns using a regular expression with a back reference.  I think this will do the trick:

```
where regexp_like(ssn, '([0-9])(\1){4}')
```

That is, find a digit and then determine if it is repeated 4 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

in sql and only if you can use a long or condition  just make use of this:

```
where col like '%11111%' or col like '%22222%' or col like '%33333%' ........
```